# How can I get Magento 2 REST API Schema and convert to C# classes

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3

Trying to find a simple way to do this properly.  I can query the REST Api in Magento and get the data from there and create classes based on the result easily enough.. but I might miss some data if it's not in the orders but is in the schemas.

So - tried getting the whole schema from :

```
example.com/rest/default/schema?services=all
```

Which gives me a swagger 2.0 result. I can't seem to actually do anything with that result.
I tried https://editor.swagger.io/  but that gives me a ton of errors

It would be good to hear from someone who has actually done this.

Answer (score 0):

when querying the schema, you will only see the endpoints you are allowed to use.

I assume you did not provide an access token, that's why you see a reduced list that will only show you the "anonymous" endpoints.

please refer to the documentation to learn more about the authentication: https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/webapi/get-started/authentication/gs-authentication-token/